# Can you use webtorrent for distributed live video broadcasting

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, webtorrent

I want to use p2p webrtc for live video streaming through webtorrent.

https://github.com/feross/webtorrent

It can apparently stream video but can it take as input webcams and other sources?

How would you do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd be very interested in the answer to this.  I'm actually distributing a stream of JSON blobs but it has two things in common with streaming a webcam: 1) For high efficiency the chunk sizes should be variable. 2) The stream is endless.  For (2) I might try giving a named pipe as the input file and tell webtorrent that the file length is 1<<64.  That doesn't deal with (1).  http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6467344&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel7%2F6451323%2F6466779%2F06467344.pdf%3Farnumber%3D6467344

Comment: It also doesn't deal with the fact that new people joining the torrent aren't interested in old data.

Answer (score 10):

Torrents are immutable, meaning that they can't change over time. You can built live streaming on top of torrents, though. You just need to pick a time interval (say 15 seconds), and create a torrent for each interval. The broadcaster should publish the .torrent files, or at least the magnet links to a central server somewhere that the clients can keep checking to get the latest content.

See https://github.com/feross/webtorrent/issues/448#issuecomment-159147568 for some discussion about how this might work.

As the creator of WebTorrent, I will say this. Live video streaming is out-of-scope for WebTorrent and should be built as a separate package on top of WebTorrent.

Comment: And then how could we merge files/chunks on the fly? I'm not sure where to look at

Comment: You're going to need to use the MediaSource API for streaming into the video tag, so you'll need to manually merge the video chunks.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Any plan for doing so?